# Can I Login to Stackoverflow using RoboForm (Password Manager)?

Tags: support, openid, login

Does anyone here use RoboForm* (or anything like it) to automatically log in to Stackoverflow?

* <sup>[RoboForm](http://www.roboform.com/) lets me log into any website using one click (automatically goes to website's login URL, fills out name/password form, "clicks" login button).</sup>

If I were logging into Yahoo Mail (for example), RoboForm would open a brower to 'mail.yahoo.com', type in my username/password, and click 'login'... automatically. So RoboForm works as both an Internet shortcut (to open a browser to the right site) and an automation tool (to log me in).

But, because of OpenID, the URL of the name/password screen is different each time I log into Stackoverflow. **I can't find a *specific* URL** (for a login page) that I can put into RoboForm to log me into my Stackoverflow account. If I try to reuse the same URL each time, it doesn't work.

I'm trying to get back that **one-click-does-all** functionality. Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: I use Roboform, but haven't found a way to bypass the extra clicks, I just have one click to do when I get to the providers site.

Comment: I use Roboform on a USB flash drive as both my "bookmarks" and password manager. Locally, I have cookies. But when I am on another computer, I have to open a browser, type in the URL, then click 'log in', then select my open ID provider before RoboForm even comes into the picture. Lazy, I know, but I was hoping to get back my one-click functionality when I was on the road throughout the day.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have your own web host, but if you do there's a neat solution that I've found and currently use - become your own OpenID provider with [phpMyID](http://siege.org/projects/phpMyID/).

One of the nice things about phpMyID is that it uses basic HTTP authentication to authorize you, so it should be easy for programs like RoboForm to remember who you are - even browsers can remember this information automatically, or in the case of Safari automatically submit it so I don't even have to enter through the form to continue - I'm automagiaclly logged in.

It requires a web host with PHP, and preferably your own domain to put it on so it's easy to type.

[image]

Comment: So you go to *your* web page and see this form. When you click 'Log In' does that automatically bring you to SO, SU, SF, or Meta automatically? Would you need four different pages to log into each site? It may not help me specifically but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: The same one for all four - it's just OpenID. And yes, once I click "Log In" I'm logged in. I don't actually see any page, blank or otherwise, just the login box, so I never really leave SO/SU/etc.

Comment: So I'm trying to figure out if you end up with a **specific, unique URL** that you could type directly into a browser that will bring you to your login form, without clicking through the OpenID pages of Stackoverflow (who's URL changes each time). *[I updated my question to, hopefully, make my question more clear]*

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at, but I don't think that it's possible with OpenID, as I'm pretty sure that the site you're signing in to has to initiate the sign-in connection. Under the circumstances, I think that getting your browser to remember your password and sign you in automatically when you provide your OpenID URL is the best you'll get.

Comment: phpMyID is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on one of the openid providers, it automatically fills in a url into the textbox.  So, for https://stackoverflow.com/login, you could have RoboForm fill in http://yahoo.com (or the url for whichever provider you use) and have it submit the form.  That should direct you to the yahoo login form, which again, RoboForm can automatically fill out for you and submit.